# Unresolved compilation: Unhandled exception type IOException

Tags: java, exception

When trying to write read an int from standard in I'm getting a compile error.

```
System.out.println("Hello Calculator : \n");        
int a=System.in.read();
```

The program throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Unhandled exception type IOException at SamplePackege.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:15)
```

How do I fix this error?

My Code :

```
try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=sc.nextInt();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: get a good java tutorial first dude.

Comment: I tried to make the question better and provided a decent answer.

Answer (score 2):

in.read() can throw a checked exception of type IOException.

You can read about Exception Handling in Java [Here.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)

You can either change your program to throw an IOException, or you can put the read in a try catch block.

```
try{
   int a=System.in.read();
catch(IOException ioe){
   ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Hello Calculator : \n");
    int a=System.in.read();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The program doesn't have a bug.

The method `read()` requires you to catch an `Exception` in case something goes wrong.

Enclose the method inside a `try/catch`statement:

```
try {
 int a = System.in.read();
 ...
}
catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In any case **I strongly suggest you to use documentation and/or Java tutorials**, in which these things are clearly stated. Programming with out using them is just pointless. You will save yourself a lot of headaches, and probably also our time.