# Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException (for some odd reason)

Tags: java

My code is very simple and straight forward. I create an empty file using the `PrintWriter` class and write the numbers 1 - 100 to the file, then close the file. As far as I know, `PrintWriter` should create the empty file, which makes me wonder why I'm getting this `FileNotFoundException` error.

```
public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args){

      PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("nums.txt");

      for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
          outputFile.println(i + 1);

      out.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: The code you are showing could not have possibly thrown a `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Could you show the full error message?

Comment: Maybe you try to execute the code in a read-only directory. Can you check?

Comment: @MikeNakis yes it can, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.lang.String). Try changing the path and see. `"C:/Documents/nums.txt"`

Comment: [Here's a link. This should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19309163/8210845)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19309163/8210845 check this out. This should help.

Comment: @EduardoDennis wh00ps! C-:=

Comment: I've added the absolute path to no avail. Print writer is suppose to create a new file so I don't understand the "FileNotFound" part. Also here's the  full error message:                                                                                           Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

 at Practice.main(Practice.java:9)

Comment: no access denied message

Comment: Awesome sauce @Dukeling!!!! throwing the exception allows me to create the empty file and write to it! thanx!!! Now my question is why does the exception need to be thrown when syntactically I should've been fine in the first place?

Comment: [Why do we need exception handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728173/why-do-we-need-exception-handling)

Comment: Just for the curious, this is actually a duplicate of [Unresolved compilation: Unhandled exception type IOException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811468/unresolved-compilation-unhandled-exception-type-ioexception) (my last comment seems to have been deleted for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
public class Practice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("C:\\Documents\\nums.txt");
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            outputFile.println(i + 1);
        }
        outputFile.close();
    }
}
```

This puts the nums text file into the documents folder.

Comment: shouldn't printwriter create the empty file in the current working directory if I don't specify a path (relative or absolute)?

Comment: It should but have you tried it this way, is there a specific place that you want the file to go?

Comment: Ive tried added an absolute path to no avail

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error only when the program attempts to create the file, under a path, that I do not have access permissions for.

Could you please check :
a. If the error message contains anything that says the 'Access is denied'
b. If so, please try mapping the file path to a folder/path that you have access permissions to.

[Code snapshot + error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3EWJ.png)

Comment: no access denied message